# Impossibility to apply closed-loop filtering techniques modelling a thin flexible structure

Tags: matlab, filtering, simulink

**Model approach:**
I am modelling on Matlab-Simulink a very thin flexible structure. All points of the model are link with each other with springs and dampers this way (without the tethers in the center):
[Mesh description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPUmB.png)

The general equation of my model applied at each point of the mesh is the following:
[Dynamic formula of mass/spring/damper system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu7Lf.png)

With k the springs stiffness, and c the dampers damping.

To adapt the physical properties of the material I want to model, the spring stiffness has been set to a very high value, around k = 5000. This mean that my spring links are highly reactive to any deformation.

**Problem:**
*This leads to my problem:* High stiffness links induce high frequency displacement that I can consider as noise in the simulation.

- The simulation is much slower as the variable time step, I am using must be very low.
- This high-frequency displacements (around 160 Hz, which the resonance frequency of the springs) stays all along the simulations.

Here is a simulation of my structure rotating at a constant angular speed:
[In-time evolution of a random point of my structure in spherical coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhDi7.png)

We can see that R is vibrating at a very high frequency. However, the displacement amplitude is clearly negligible.
***To speed up the simulation, I want to suppress those vibrations!***

**Investigation:**
To suppress them, I investigate on signal filtering techniques, mainly low-pass filtering. On every loop of our simulation, and what should enter our filter are data of all my points in all my axis.
[Simulink low-pass filter block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p14J.png)

The continuous version of low-pass filter in Simulink library has been tested on the acceleration, the speed and the position, with several cut-off frequencies from 100 Hz to 500 Hz.

For example, for a cut-off frequency of 200Hz and filtering the position at t=0.6 sec I have:
[In-time filtered evolution of a random point of my structure in spherical coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjJyV.png)

It is an in-plane movement so I don’t have any elevation angle, but azimuth angle and point distance from the center are completely diverging.

The problem might come from:

- The fact that I am in a closed-loop system
- The fact that for the mesh we have, the filter receives 81 vectors of 3*1 at each time step and maybe the filter block is not made to function with that.

The fact that for the mesh we have, the filter receives 81 vectors of 3*1 at each time step and maybe the filter block is not made to function with that.

**Main question:**
Are there filtering techniques for closed-loop and multiple inputs system that could solve my problem?

Comment: In general, this question is very hard to understand. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, just a comment, a spring mass system is equivalent to a linear filter. Adding a filter to a filter doesn't feel like a solution to whatever your problem is. It could be that your 'high stiffness links' are not creating 'noise', but evincing the true and correct behavior of the system---which is not behaving as expected. Just guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

Digital filter designer works with SISO signals. Just demux your signals and apply some lowpass filters. You gave lots of info that made it harder to understand the core problem, if there is anything else you can re-iterate. I'd start with a 3rd order Butterworth LPF wc at around 100Hz for your needs.

Comment: Hi GuarneerFPS, thanks for taking the time to answer. Indeed there is a lot of info and I couldn't find a way to oversimplify the problem. But thanks for the input I'll try the demux idea, and see if I can go with the filter you propose !